# Will a bullet be split in half if it hits a butter knife that is fixed in place?

Tags: physics, weapons, guns

I was reading [a manga](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Manga/DragonsRioting), [and I saw this](http://www.mangahere.co/manga/dragons_rioting/c018/21.html):

[image]

So I was wondering. Will a bullet be split in half if it hits a butter knife that is fixed in place? Have there been experiments to test that?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

In the television show [Penn and Teller Tell A Lie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penn_%26_Teller_Tell_a_Lie), a competitor to Mythbusters, they conduct an experiment to try this.

Here is a [YouTube video](http://youtu.be/1Qy-Be2cDGQ?t=1m35s) of the result.

In the single instance they show with a slow motion camera, the bullet is indeed at split in half - or at least, fragmented into pieces - by a normal butter-knife. This is not a large sample, and doesn't demonstrate it works with all bullets or all butter knives, but shows that it is, in fact, possible.

---

Bonus: [Another video on the stunt using a machete](http://youtu.be/R9hWoNZdx-w) from a source I have no particular reason to trust.

Comment: and the mythbusters got it to work on an axe

Comment: That makes sense for soft slugs designed to be stopped by flesh. I wonder how armor-piercing bullets would fare.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman From experience (not exactly with butter knives), I can safely say that this won't work with almost all types of armor-piercing bullet.

Comment: I'd say what there was a fragmentation of bullet rather than splitting of it in half... Unfortunately, Penn&Teller didn't went into closer details like bullet type (I'd say it was .45ACP Ball) and damage done the blade. @ratchetfreak, even dullest of axe blades is far superior comparing with butter knife. see also http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FiIxUUu6Ojk Also, I;ve seen SOG commercial entitled "knives can do that" featuring an expansive bullet **accurately** split by hitting the tactical knife edge

Comment: @FreeConsulting: Yes, now you mention it, I think fragmentation is a better description.

Answer (score 8):

Mythbusters conducted a similiar experiment. But they used an axe. The answer is yes. It is possible. At least with a particular type of axe and with the particular bullet and gun, and with the right distance. [quoting Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MythBusters_%282009_season%29#Davy_Crockett.27s_Magic_Bullet):

> After setting up a target and sticking an axe in it, the Build Team
>   received training from an expert in antique American firearms and
>   began shooting from 40 yards (37 m). Each member took three shots,
>   moving up to 20 yards (18 m) after Tory went first. Although several
>   bullets nicked the blade or handle, none split on it until Tory tried
>   again with a stand at the shorter distance. With one bullet hole
>   appearing on either side of the blade, the team declared the myth
>   confirmed and decided that a person could consistently make the
>   40-yard shot with enough practice. In addition the expert then
>   proceeded to show the 40-yd.-shot standing, cleanly bursting two
>   balloons located to the left and right of the axe blade.